# VBA: Updating Pivots Issues

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am relatively new to VBA, at the moment when trying to update a pivot, I get the following **error Run-time  error 1004**,
The Pivot seems not to be taking the data set correctly as on the pivot there are missing dates which are correctly formatted on the Dataset.

When I run the macro it stops right on DateVal line, please feel free to ask for more details if needed.

I tried adding manually dates that are part of the dataset with the same result but if I select dates running the Record Macro it'll work but and the if I run the macro created by the Recorder I would get the same Error, I hope you can show me where I am wrong on this code.

```
Sub UpdatePivots()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DateVal As String
DateVal = Sheets("home").[G16]
DateFormat = Sheets("home").[Q10]

' Find the last row with data in column A
Sheets("GLViewFinanceCycleCounts").Select
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'Remove Filters if exists
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

pName = ActiveWorkbook.Path      ' the path of the currently active file
wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name     ' the file name of the currently active file
shtName = ActiveSheet.Name       ' the name of the currently selected worksheet
DatasetRange = Range("A1:BM" & LastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
DatasetPT = pName & "\[" & wbName & "]" & shtName & "!" & DatasetRange

' Pivot Updates
' CompletesAndSH page
Sheets("CompletesAndSH").Select ' Pivot Table Page
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DatasetPT, Version:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14)
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
' Filter to selected month
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name").CurrentPage = DateVal
```

Comment: Which dateVal line does the error occur on?  This one: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name").CurrentPage = DateVal  ? Also, where possible swop Activesheet for named sheets. Maybe put the relevant sheets in variables and use those.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, yes that is the line with the issue, thanks will take the advise.

Comment: Try swopping ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41") to using the expected worksheet name in front. Worksheets("yourSheet").PivotTables("PivotTable41")

Comment: Just tried it but didn't work I keep getting the same error

Comment: Tried recording the action just for that step using the macro recorder and compare against your syntax. Also, verify what the value of DateVal is when the error occurs.

Comment: I tried that already, and I put in the code generated by the macro recorder but keep coming up with the same error, I verify the value  after the error, what I notice is that there are dates on the Dataset which the pivot is not picking up even when refresh it manually.